# How to change focus on page load in javascript for flash game?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, haml

This is my code for flash object generated in html:
`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="coloredconfusion" data="xxx-game-path" width="700" height="600">...</object>`

And in haml I have:

```
:javascript
     $(document).ready(function() {
         document.getElementById('#{@game.codename}').focus();
     });
```

I want the game to be focused after it is loaded. Is it even possible? What is the right way?

Comment: @sawa no. my code is not focusing on the game.

Comment: What JavaScript error do you get?

Comment: More importantly, what does the JavaScript source look like when rendered? View source and see how it shows up in the client. Also, if you're using jQuery, why not `$('...').focus()` instead of doing it the hard way?

Comment: @sawa `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null `

Comment: @tadman
JS is rendered properly:
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('coloredconfusion').focus();
          });
        </script>

Comment: It seems that JS is executed before flash object is loaded and this is wy I'm getting thath error. Am I thinking right? @tadman

Comment: On the webpage, can you open a developer's tool and see if you actually have the `<object>` with `id` `coloredconfusion`?

Comment: You may have to periodically check for the presence of your element using a timer if it's not clear when that `<object>` element will appear.

Comment: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="coloredconfusion" data="path" width="700" height="600"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="flashvars" value="token=e7299020e570b23078185cf283c327f7&amp;url=/game_results?locale=en&amp;redirect=/dashboard?locale=en&amp;startlevel=null&amp;json={&quot;startlevel&quot;:null,&quot;workout_mode&quot;:false,&quot;showtutorial&quot;:true,&quot;force_tutorial&quot;:true,&quot;level_scores&quot;:null,&quot;config_id&quot;:3}&amp;id=coloredconfusion"></object>` @sawa

Comment: @tadman how should I do this? I'm not very strong with JS :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to wait around for it to show up, this might work:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var app = $('#coloredfusion');

  if (app[0]) {
    app.focus();
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 500);
```

That'll poll every 500ms for the presence of the element, and when it finds it, will focus it and stop checking.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following successfully in the Flash app - it calls back to JavaScript to set the focus, after the app is created (in the creationComplete event handler):

```
// Force the browser to give focus to the app
ExternalInterface.call('function() { var app = document.getElementById("appName"); app.focus(); }');
```

Replace "appName" with your actual application name.